# Isolating a function which depends on another in a unit test in Python

Tags: python, unit-testing

I was reading [this post](https://jeffknupp.com/blog/2013/12/09/improve-your-python-understanding-unit-testing/) about unit testing. In the post, the function `print_next_prime` relies on the function `is_prime` which has to be called for multiple sequential values (probably). The author states

> Since unit tests test only a single unit at a time, we would need to think carefully about how we could accurately test `print_next_prime` (more on how this is accomplished later).

but he never comes back to this concept.  How would one go about accurately testing `print_next_prime`?

**EDIT:**

The relevant functions are:

```
def is_prime(number):
    """Return True if *number* is prime."""
    for element in range(2, number):
        if number % element == 0:
            return False
    return True

def print_next_prime(number):
    """Print the closest prime number larger than *number*."""
    index = number
    while True:
        index += 1
        if is_prime(index):
            print(index)
```

Comment: I could think of two ways: mock `is_prime`, or treat `is_prime` as part of the unit. Neither addresses the issue that `print_next_prime` encapsulates an infinite loop: how do you test a function that never returns when you call it?

Comment: True.  Perhaps a `next_prime` function with `return index` in the last line would serve as a better example.

Comment: Nobody can answer, because then we'd be speaking for the author. It looks like it falls under the topic of "writing testable code" meaning the design of print_next_prime makes it fundamentally difficult to unit test. It has side effects. It has dependencies on other units. Chepner notes some of these. Mocking is one technique for separating a unit which depends on other code to function.

Comment: It looks like @jknupp is around on Stack Overflow, and seen recently. I don't know if tagging him like this will actually work, but I figure it's worth a shot ;)